# Query by Enum in RavenDB

Tags: enums, ravendb

I have used the convention:

```
store.Conventions.SaveEnumsAsIntegers = true;
```

Enums are now being persisted as integers correctly, but, when i try to query using an enum the query gets translated with the enums in their string representation, which gives me no results.

```
session.Query<Entity>().Where(x => x.EnumProp == MyEnum.Value1);
```

It was my impression that SaveEnumsAsIntegers converts both when persisted and when querying as per this post:

[Querying an enum property persisted as an integer is not working](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ravendb/GP73s4JSsn0)

Can anyone help ?

Comment: What build are you using? (Server & Client).

Comment: @AyendeRahien I'm using the latest, 2330.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this against RavenDB 2330 and it is working as expected.

See the passing unit test [here](https://gist.github.com/mj1856/5263362).

If there's something you are doing differently, please update your question.  Thanks.